# Save an already opened new Excel workbook using autoit

Tags: excel, autoit

A windows application exports data into a new excel workbook.
I need to save that generated workbook using AutoIt.
I tried the below code.But it is not working.

```
Local $oExcel = ObjGet("","Excel.Application")
For $oWb in $oExcel.Workbooks
$oWb.Activate()
_Excel_BookSaveAs($oWb,"File name with full path",Default,True)
$oWb.Application.Quit
ExitLoop
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you have to make sure your file extension and excel type match - i.e.  Excel 2007 = xlsx

A valid path/file name, a valid type ( optional ) , overwrite = true.
Activate isn't necessary.

```
#include <excel.au3>
#include <ExcelConstants.au3>

Local $oExcel = ObjGet("","Excel.Application")


if NOT @error then
  for $Workbook in $oExcel.Workbooks
    ; optional type $xlExcel7  
    ; optional overwrite = true
    _Excel_BookSaveAs($Workbook,"c:\drivers\keeper3.xlsx"   ) 
  next
  _Excel_Close($oExcel,false,true)
EndIf

ConsoleWrite("END" & @CRLF)
```